# NullPointerException while retrieving edittext values in onPause in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have 3 tab fragments in viewpager. I am sending data from 1st and 2nd fragment to 3rd fragment.
I have implemented selection of images using custom gallery in the 1st fragment(in this on clicking an imageview a custom gallery activity is displayed and then the selected images are displayed in the 1st fragment)
I have other form data which I am retrieving in onPause() method and I am passing this values to 3rd fragment via interface(1st fragment->activity->3rd fragment gets the data)

Now when I dont click on the imageview(i.e dont go to custom gallery activity) all the other form data are passed to the 3rd fragment with no issues.

But when I click on imageview and visit custom gallery activity selecting images and coming back to my 1st fragment..obviously onPause is been called before going to gallery activity..
where I am handling exceptions using try-catch

But the problem is after this my other form datas that I have filled in the 1st fragment are not been passed to 3rd fragment even if I fill them after I select the images first.

I get null values in my 3rd fragment when I visit custom gallery activity from the 1st one.

I debugged values using log.. and I found that one of the form data values was printed but at the very next moment it displayed **"++LOG:entry corrupt or truncated"**

I researched for this error and I have found this happens either when the value is too large or when the value is null..
Also I was receiving **Invalid Number Format: invalid int ""** in my 3rd fragment where I was trying to get one of the form data integer values of 1st fragment.The Log and the above exception clearly shows that its because I am getting null values in my 3rd fragment..

Please Help me what approach should I use?To achieve what I need. and since I am a newbie in fragments I am going wrong somewhere..

This is my TabActivity --> SubmitPostActivity

```
    package com.jbandroid;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.jbandroid.model.TabsPagerAdapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import com.jbandroid.fragment.*;
import com.jbandroid.gallery.CustomGallery;

public class SubmitPostActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener,PostInfoFragment.setPostInfo,LocationInfoFragment.setLocationInfo{

    private ViewPager viewpager;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
     FragmentManager manager;
     PersonalInfoFragment frag;


    //Tab titles
    private String[] tabs  = {"Post Info" , "Location Info" , "Personal Info" };


    //defining form input variables
    /*private String post_title,post_desc,post_start_date,post_end_date,post_country,post_city,post_area,
    post_user_name,post_user_email,post_user_phone;

    private int post_category_id, post_image,post_price, post_quantity;*/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.action_submit_post);

        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        //viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        viewpager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        //actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        for (String tab : tabs){
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab).setTabListener(this));
        }

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem( savedInstanceState.getInt("tab",0));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */

        viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("tab", getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view

        viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }


    @Override
    public void pass_location_details(String country, String city, String area) {

         frag = (PersonalInfoFragment) manager.findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + viewpager.getId() + ":" + 2);
        frag.get_post_location_details(country, city, area);
        Log.d("submitarea", area);
    }

    @Override
    public void pass_post_details(List<String> post_details) {
         frag = (PersonalInfoFragment) manager.findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + viewpager.getId() + ":" + 2);
            frag.get_post_details(post_details);
            Log.d("submitpostinfo","hello"+ post_details.get(5));
    }


}
```

This is my 1st fragment --> PostInfoFragment. I have tried to cut short the code.

```
  package com.jbandroid.fragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.jbandroid.R;
import com.jbandroid.SubmitPostActivity;
import com.jbandroid.gallery.Action;
import com.jbandroid.gallery.CustomGallery;
import com.jbandroid.gallery.CustomGalleryAdapter;


import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.memory.impl.WeakMemoryCache;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

public class PostInfoFragment extends Fragment {

    private MenuItem myActionMenuItem;
      private Button myActionButton;
      private ActionBar actionBar;
      private String post_title,post_desc,post_price,post_quantity,post_category_id;
    //  int  post_category_id = 0;

      private EditText submit_post_title,submit_post_desc,
      submit_post_total_price,submit_post_total_quantity;

    private SubmitPostActivity s;
    setPostInfo info;
    List<String> post_details;

    private LinearLayout submit_post_total_quantity_linear;

    ImageView submit_post_img;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Handler handler;
    private GridView gridGallery;
    private CustomGalleryAdapter adapter;
    private ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;
    private ImageView imgSinglePick;
    private ArrayList<CustomGallery> dataT;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post_info, container, false);
        initImageLoader();
        gridGallery = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgGridGallery);

handler = new Handler();

        gridGallery.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        adapter = new CustomGalleryAdapter(getActivity(), imageLoader);
        adapter.setMultiplePick(false);
        gridGallery.setAdapter(adapter);

        viewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher);
        viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(1);

        imgSinglePick = (ImageView)rootView. findViewById(R.id.imgSinglePick);


        //s = (SubmitPostActivity)getActivity();
         submit_post_title = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit_post_title);
         submit_post_desc = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit_post_description);

         submit_post_total_price  = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit_post_total_price);
         submit_post_total_quantity = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit_post_total_quantity);

         submit_post_total_quantity_linear = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit_post_total_qty_linear);


        actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);


        post_details = new ArrayList<String>();
         res = getResources();


        setListeners();



        return rootView;

    }


    private void setListeners(){
        gridGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int postion,
                    long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(Action.ACTION_MULTIPLE_PICK);

                startActivityForResult(i, 200);

            }
        });


imgSinglePick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Action.ACTION_MULTIPLE_PICK);
                startActivityForResult(i, 200);


                /*for single pick
                 * Intent i = new Intent(Action.ACTION_PICK);
                startActivityForResult(i, 100);*/
            }
        });


final TypedArray selectedValues = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.categoryValues);


submit_post_total_quantity_linear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        submit_post_total_quantity.requestFocus();
    }
});

}


    private void initImageLoader() {
        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .cacheOnDisc().imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder builder = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
        getActivity()).defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions).memoryCache(
        new WeakMemoryCache());

ImageLoaderConfiguration config = builder.build();
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(config);       
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


         if (requestCode == 200 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                String[] all_path = data.getStringArrayExtra("allpath");

                 dataT = new ArrayList<CustomGallery>();

                for (String string : all_path) {
                    CustomGallery item = new CustomGallery();
                    item.sdcardPath = string;
                    dataT.add(item);
                    Log.d("selected", string);
                }

                viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(0);
                adapter.addAll(dataT);
            }else if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                adapter.clear();

                viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(1);
                String single_path = data.getStringExtra("single_path");
                imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + single_path, imgSinglePick);

            }else{
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }


    }



    public interface setPostInfo{
        public void pass_post_details(List<String> post_details);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try{
        info = (setPostInfo)activity;
        }catch(ClassCastException e){

            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + "must implemet setPostInfo");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
           super.onPause();


           passFormInputs();

    }





    private void passFormInputs(){
        try{
            post_title = submit_post_title.getText().toString();
            post_desc = submit_post_desc.getText().toString();

            post_price = submit_post_total_price.getText().toString();
            post_quantity = submit_post_total_quantity.getText().toString();


            post_details.add(post_title);

            post_details.add(post_desc);

            post_details.add(post_quantity);

            post_details.add(post_price);

            post_details.add(post_category_id);
            Log.d("post_info", "hello"+ post_details.get(2) );
            Log.d("post_info1", "llo"+ post_quantity );
            info.pass_post_details(post_details);

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }


}
```

2nd Fragment also has some 3-4 fields and passing those data to 3rd fragment..

This is my 3rd Fragment-->PersonalInfoFragment

```
   package com.jbandroid.fragment;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.jbandroid.PostActivity;
import com.jbandroid.R;
import com.jbandroid.gallery.CustomGallery;
import com.jbandroid.mobileservice.Post;
import com.jbandroid.model.ToastActivity;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceTable;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.ServiceFilterResponse;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.TableOperationCallback;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.*;

public class PersonalInfoFragment extends Fragment {

    private MenuItem myActionMenuItem;
      private Button myActionButton;
     private ActionBar actionBar;

      List<String> post_details;
      ArrayList<CustomGallery> selected;
      private MobileServiceClient mClient;
    private MobileServiceTable<Post> post_table;
    String country,city,area,user_name,user_email,user_phone;
    Post post;
    private EditText submit_post_user_name;
    private EditText submit_post_user_email;
    private EditText submit_post_user_phone;
    ToastActivity toastActivity;
    private CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;

    List<String> imageName;



    CloudBlobClient blobClient;
    CloudBlobContainer blobContainer;
    BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personal_info,container,false);
        actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);


        imageName = new ArrayList<String>();


        submit_post_user_name = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit_post_user_name);
        submit_post_user_email = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit_post_user_email);
        submit_post_user_phone = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit_post_user_phone);
        toastActivity =  new ToastActivity();





        post = new Post();

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public void get_post_details(List<String> post_details){
        this.post_details = post_details;
    //  this.selected = selected;
        Log.d("personalfrag(postinfo)", post_details.get(5));
    }

    public void get_post_location_details(String country,String city,String area){
        this.country = country;
        this.city = city;
        this.area = area;
        Log.d("personal", area);
    }

    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater) {
         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

            // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar

            inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);

            // Here we get the action view we defined
            myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.my_action);
            View actionView = myActionMenuItem.getActionView();

            // We then get the button view that is part of the action view
            if(actionView != null) {
              myActionButton = (Button) actionView.findViewById(R.id.action_btn);
              myActionButton.setText(R.string.txt_submit);
              if(myActionButton != null) {
                // We set a listener that will be called when the return/enter key is pressed
                myActionButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        myActionButton.setEnabled(false);

                        myActionButton.setText("Submitting..");

                        setPostItems();

                        insertintodb();

                        Log.d("postinfo",post_details.get(2));

                    //toastActivity.displayToast(getActivity(), post_details.get(0));
                    }
                });

              }
            }
    }

    public void setPostItems(){
        user_name = submit_post_user_name.getText().toString();
        user_email = submit_post_user_email.getText().toString();
        user_phone = submit_post_user_phone.getText().toString();

        //this values are from 1st fragment
        post.setPost_name(post_details.get(0));

        post.setPost_description(post_details.get(1));

        post.setPost_totalquantity((Integer.valueOf(post_details.get(2))).intValue());

        post.setPost_total_price((Integer.valueOf(post_details.get(3))).intValue());

        post.setCategory_id((Integer.valueOf(post_details.get(4))).intValue());

        //this values are from 2nd fragment
        post.setPost_country(country);
        post.setPost_city(city);
        post.setPost_area(area);

        //this values are from this fragment
        post.setPost_user_name(user_name);
        post.setPost_user_email(user_email);
        post.setPost_user_phone(user_phone);
        post.setPost_user_id(1);


    }

    public void insertintodb(){
        if(mClient == null)
        {
            return;
        }


        if(isOnline()){
            post_table.insert(post, new TableOperationCallback<Post>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Post post, Exception exception,
                        ServiceFilterResponse response) {

                    if(exception == null){

                        toastActivity.displayToast(getActivity(), "Post Submitted");

                    }else{
                        //toastActivity.displayToast(getActivity(), "Error:"+exception.toString());
                        toastActivity.displayToast(getActivity(), "Problem Connecting to Server");
                        Log.d("error",exception.toString(),exception.getCause());
                    }
                }
            });

            }else{
                toastActivity.displayToast(getActivity(), "Sorry! No internet connection");
            }

        myActionButton.setEnabled(true);
        myActionButton.setText(R.string.txt_submit);

    }


    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

StackTrace:

```
     10-09 12:14:57.221: D/personal(546): Vasai
10-09 12:14:57.231: D/submitarea(546): Vasai
10-09 12:14:59.751: D/post_info(546): hello
10-09 12:14:59.751: D/post_info1(546): llo45
10-09 12:14:59.751: D/post_info1(546): +++ LOG: entry corrupt or truncated
10-09 12:14:59.761: D/submitpostinfo(546): hello
10-09 12:15:08.260: D/AndroidRuntime(546): Shutting down VM
10-09 12:15:08.260: W/dalvikvm(546): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
10-09 12:15:08.300: E/AndroidRuntime(546): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 12:15:08.300: E/AndroidRuntime(546): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
10-09 12:15:08.300: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
10-09 12:15:08.300: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
10-09 12:15:08.300: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
10-09 12:15:08.300: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:490)
10-09 12:15:08.300: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at com.jbandroid.fragment.PersonalInfoFragment.setPostItems(PersonalInfoFragment.java:198)
10-09 12:15:08.300: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at com.jbandroid.fragment.PersonalInfoFragment$1.onClick(PersonalInfoFragment.java:177)
10-09 12:15:08.300: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
10-09 12:15:08.300: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
10-09 12:15:08.300: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-09 12:15:08.300: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-09 12:15:08.300: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-09 12:15:08.300: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
10-09 12:15:08.300: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 12:15:08.300: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-09 12:15:08.300: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-09 12:15:08.300: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-09 12:15:08.300: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 12:15:11.705: D/gralloc_goldfish(576): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Also you can see in the stacktrace..

```
Log.d("post_info", "hello"+ post_details.get(2) );
Log.d("post_info1", "llo"+ post_quantity );
```

post_quantity value is being printed while post_details.get(2) is empty..cant understand this behaviour.

**UPDATE:**  I found the issue(it was improper exception handling).. when I am going to custom gallery activity from my 1st fragment.. onPause is called.. and here I am not handling the exception properly since my list is being filled with empty data..as all the add functions are being called and then the exception is thrown..i.e. the exception is thrown in the line

```
    info.pass_post_details(post_details);
```

in passFormInputs() method.. so the code before this line is anyhow executed..now the next time when onPause is called again.. now actually my real values are added in the list below the empty values. I had total 10 values in mmy list and when I tried to print the 11th value I got my 1st value printed..

Comment: Some code and a stack trace would help to diagnose this problem.

Comment: okk will add in a few

Answer (score 0):

As the stacktrace suggest. It's a `NumberFormatException, invalid int ""`. in `PersonalInfoFragment`

The problem of your code is that you never checked what is being returned by calling `post_items.get(2);` before calling `Integer.valueOf()`.

My suggestion is to check what is returned from `post_items.get(2)` before calling `Integer.valueOf()` and wrap `Integer.valueOf` in a try-catch block

```
String quantityStr = post_details.get(2);
if(quantityStr != null && quantityStr.length() > 0)
{
    try{
        int qty = Integer.valueOf(quantityStr);
        //Do your logic.
    }catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        //Unable to parse, not a valid int
    }
}
```

Comment: its giving invalid int ""..since the value is null..cz I even tried to print its string value appending it with hello..hello is being printed but not this value.. that means the string is empty..and I am trying to convert an empty value into integer hence causing numberformatexception..

Comment: I added this in my button click.. String quantityStr = post_details.get(5);
      if(quantityStr != null && quantityStr.length() > 0)
      {
          try{
              int qty = Integer.valueOf(quantityStr);
              //Do your logic.
              Log.d("personal(insidesubmit)", "qty is not null");
              toastActivity.displayToast(getActivity(), "qty is not null");
          }catch(NumberFormatException e)
          {
               //Unable to parse, not a valid int
          }
}else{       Log.d("personal(insidesubmit)", "qty is null");}
and I got "qty is null" in my log..